# If I want to make this player move, will the currently structure give me problems down the line?

Tags: java

I've made a constructor in **class Player** and are now making my object **Player one** in **class MyFrame**, the same class where i paint()/paintComponent() other objects, but is this structure **Player one**  okay if I want to make it move? Should I just change xPostmp and yPostmp in another method or would this just give me more problems down the line?

**class MyFrame**

```
             public void player(Graphics g) {
                        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                        Player one = new Player("playerOneOrange", Color.orange, xPostmp, yPostmp, sizeHead);  

                        Ellipse2D.Double playerOneOrange = new Ellipse2D.Double(xPostmp, yPostmp, sizeHead, sizeHead);
                        g2d.setColor(one.getColor());
}
```

**class Player**

```
    public Player(String playerNum, Color color, int xPostmp, int yPostmp, int sizeHead) {
        this.playerNum = playerNum;
        this.color = color;
        this.xPostmp = xPostmp;
        this.yPostmp = yPostmp;
        this.sizeHead = sizeHead;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Is your question whether it's good design for you to store the player's position as variables inside its object and then update them with setter methods? If that's the question then the answer is yes that's perfectly acceptable design for many (but not all) situations.

Comment: @sprinter - Thank you for your comment. It was exactly my question, as I want to make this visually move around. Again, thank you for clearing this for me.